# JavaScript addEventListener calls function but fails to update global variable

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, addeventlistener, variable-assignment

Bear with me, as I am a novice.

I'm coding in JavaScript and using an `.addEventListener` on `document.getElementById("texts")` to track changes in an HTML dropdown. The `.addEventListener` calls the function `changeTextValue` whenever a selection is made. This part is working, as I can `console.log` from within the function, and my conditional logic within the function is properly executed and sent to the console from within the function. However, the whole point of the function is to update a variable (`text`) outside the function every time the mouse event occurs. I've assigned the function to the variable, and I've included a return statement in the function with the proper local variable. All of this is working, the assignment is initially made outside the scope of the function and prints to the console when the page first loads. However, the variable value never updates outside the function when the mouse event occurs. Whereas the `console.log`s within the function do update when the event occurs.

I tried merely initializing the variable `text` without assigning it a value. But then I get an error that '`text.toLowerCase()`' is undefined.

I tried initializing `text` as an empty array. And then inserting `text` (in place of `chosenText`) into the function, prefixing it with `window` to access it as a global variable. This threw up an error:  '`text.toLowerCase()`' is not a function. This error goes away when I return the code to the way I am posting it, keeping the `text` variable outside the function, but assigning the function to the variable.

I feel like I'm missing something basic. Thanks for your help.

```js
'use strict';

const mobyDickText=`Moby Dick text....`;
const huckFinnText=`Huck Finn text....`;
let dropdown = document.getElementById("texts");
let pick=dropdown.value;
const title=pick;
let chosenText;
let text= changeTextValue();
let letterCount;
let lowercaseText;

document.getElementById("book-title").innerHTML = title;

function changeTextValue() {
    pick = dropdown.value;
    if (pick === "huckFinnText") {
         chosenText = huckFinnText;
        console.log(chosenText);
    } else if (pick === "mobyDickText") {
        chosenText = mobyDickText;
        console.log(chosenText);
    } return chosenText;
}

console.log(text);

document.getElementById("texts").addEventListener("change", changeTextValue);

function countFunction(letter) {
    let letterCount=0;
    lowercaseText=text.toLowerCase();
    for (let i=0; i<=text.length-1; i++) {
      if (letter === lowercaseText.charAt(i)) {
          letterCount++;
      }
    } return letterCount;
  } 

const a = countFunction("a");
const b = countFunction("b");
const c = countFunction("c");
const d = countFunction("d");
const e = countFunction("e");
const f = countFunction("f");
const g = countFunction("g");
const h = countFunction("h");
const i = countFunction("i");
const j = countFunction("j");
const k = countFunction("k");
const l = countFunction("l");
const m = countFunction("m");
const n = countFunction("n");
const o = countFunction("o");
const p = countFunction("p");
const q = countFunction("q");
const r = countFunction("r");
const s = countFunction("s");
const t = countFunction("t");
const u = countFunction("u");
const v = countFunction("v");
const w = countFunction("w");
const x = countFunction("x");
const y = countFunction("y");
const z = countFunction("z");

const letters = {
    "A": a,
    "B": b,
    "C": c,
    "D": d,
    "E": e,
    "F": f,
    "G": g,
    "H": h,
    "I": i,
    "J": j,
    "K": k,
    "L": l,
    "M": m,
    "N": n,
    "O": o,
    "P": p,
    "Q": q,
    "R": r,
    "S": s,
    "T": t,
    "U": u,
    "V": v,
    "W": w,
    "X": x,
    "Y": y,
    "Z": z
};

let sortable = [];
for (var num in letters) {
    sortable.push([num, letters[num]]);
}
const sorted=sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

let sortedNumbers = [];
for (var value in sorted) {
    sortedNumbers.push(sorted[value][1]);
}

let sortedLetters = [];
for (var value in sorted) {
    sortedLetters.push(sorted[value][0]);
}

for (let item=0; item<sorted.length; item++) {
    let strLetter = item.toString();
    document.getElementById(strLetter).innerHTML = sortedLetters[item];
}

for (let item=0; item<sorted.length; item++) {
    let strNumber = item.toString() + "n";
    document.getElementById(strNumber).innerHTML = sortedNumbers[item].toLocaleString();
} 

let total=0;
for (let item=0; item<sorted.length; item++) {
    total += sortedNumbers[item];
} document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toLocaleString();

let percent = [];
for (var num in sortedNumbers) {
    percent.push((sortedNumbers[num] / total) * 100);
    document.getElementById(num + "p").innerHTML = percent[num].toFixed(1) + "%";
}
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="main">
        <form id="form">
            <select id= "texts" name="texts" class="select">
                <option value="mobyDickText" id="mobyDick">Moby Dick</option> 
                <option value="huckFinnText" id="huckFinn">Huck Finn</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <table class="result">
            <tbody>
                <th class="title" colspan="3" id="book-title"></th>
                <tr><td id="0" class="letter"></td><td id="0n" class="number"></td><td id="0p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="1" class="letter"></td><td id="1n" class="number"></td><td id="1p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="2" class="letter"></td><td id="2n" class="number"></td><td id="2p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="3" class="letter"></td><td id="3n" class="number"></td><td id="3p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="4" class="letter"></td><td id="4n" class="number"></td><td id="4p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="5" class="letter"></td><td id="5n" class="number"></td><td id="5p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="6" class="letter"></td><td id="6n" class="number"></td><td id="6p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="7" class="letter"></td><td id="7n" class="number"></td><td id="7p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="8" class="letter"></td><td id="8n" class="number"></td><td id="8p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="9" class="letter"></td><td id="9n" class="number"></td><td id="9p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="10" class="letter"></td><td id="10n" class="number"></td><td id="10p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="11" class="letter"></td><td id="11n" class="number"></td><td id="11p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="12" class="letter"></td><td id="12n" class="number"></td><td id="12p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="13" class="letter"></td><td id="13n" class="number"></td><td id="13p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="14" class="letter"></td><td id="14n" class="number"></td><td id="14p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="15" class="letter"></td><td id="15n" class="number"></td><td id="15p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="16" class="letter"></td><td id="16n" class="number"></td><td id="16p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="17" class="letter"></td><td id="17n" class="number"></td><td id="17p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="18" class="letter"></td><td id="18n" class="number"></td><td id="18p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="19" class="letter"></td><td id="19n" class="number"></td><td id="19p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="20" class="letter"></td><td id="20n" class="number"></td><td id="20p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="21" class="letter"></td><td id="21n" class="number"></td><td id="21p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="22" class="letter"></td><td id="22n" class="number"></td><td id="22p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="23" class="letter"></td><td id="23n" class="number"></td><td id="23p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="24" class="letter"></td><td id="24n" class="number"></td><td id="24p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="25" class="letter"></td><td id="25n" class="number"></td><td id="25p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="footer" colspan="3" id="total"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```
````

Comment: ive looked at it, its working, im not sure what youre actuually trying to do though

Comment: I'm trying to update the HTML table when the user makes a selection on the dropdown.

Comment: what the total at the bottom

Comment: Even though the function is being executed, as we can see in console.log, it is not making a new assignment to the variable when the user makes a selection even though its retun value changes. How to I update the 'text' variable outside the function whenever a new addEventListener event occurs?

Comment: oh sorry, you have to remove the line "let chosenText = [];" in changeTextValue function, its overriding the scope of the external variable

Comment: The program will analyze a string of text and counts the occurences of each letter and displays them in a table. The total at the bottom is the total number of letters in the text/book.

Comment: come and chat on javascript chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: I tried removing that line, but the program gives the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the chat invite! I can't post yet because I don't have 20 reputation points, because I'm brand new.

Comment: What are all the `aCount`, `bCount`, etc. variables for? You never use them.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. I had originally planned a different way of doing it, but changed course. You are right, they can be deleted.

Comment: I've edited the code by removing the aCount, bCount, etc. variables. Still getting the same result. HTML doc doesn't update when mouse event occurs.

Comment: @mattrichards Thank you again for helping me yesterday. And thank you for the positive/encouraging feedback as well. It can be intimidating as a newbie, but I’m determined to get professionally proficient in JS. It is wonderful that people like you are willing to help us newbies :)

Comment: @Barmar Thank you again for helping me yesterday by pointing out the 26 variables I wasn’t using. :)  appreciate you looking over my code!

Comment: @ivanheyman, hey buddy hope your programs going well, nobody told me this, but youre supposed to upvote answers that you find helpful, dont be shy, i dont mean me now or anything, just dont forget in the future and you'll hopefully sail along nicely on this site, its a big part of people helping you, chat again soon

Comment: @mattrichards Hey Matt, thanks for the tip! I didn’t even see the upvote arrows. I did just give your answer an up vote, but it told me I need 15 reputation to vote, but that my feedback has been recorded.

Comment: @ivanheyman, i really didnt mean me, i was just happy being able to help, if you try to increase your rep dont ask too many questions chances are you'll get downvotes in the end, try to do it through answering questions preferably, as soon as you get your 20 rep head over to that javascript chat room, good luck buddy

Comment: if you go to where the questions come in and wait for someone new to ask one that you might be able to answer or find the answer to quite quickly, then answer it and you might get an upvote quite easily

Comment: one last thing, if you do answer a question, make sure youre actually answering the question, sometimes its easy to post an answer and later realise you didnt actually answer what was being asked and get downvoted for it

Comment: @mattrichards Thanks for all the tips, Matt. I really appreciate it! I'm eager to get into that chatroom :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here you go :)

you werent too far off

```js
'use strict';

let aCount = 0,
  bCount = 0,
  cCount = 0,
  dCount = 0,
  eCount = 0,
  fCount = 0,
  gCount = 0,
  hCount = 0,
  iCount = 0,
  jCount = 0,
  kCount = 0,
  lCount = 0,
  mCount = 0,
  nCount = 0,
  oCount = 0,
  pCount = 0,
  qCount = 0,
  rCount = 0,
  sCount = 0,
  tCount = 0,
  uCount = 0,
  vCount = 0,
  wCount = 0,
  xCount = 0,
  yCount = 0,
  zCount = 0;

const mobyDickText=`Moby Dick text....`;
const huckFinnText=`Huck Finn text....`;
let dropdown = document.getElementById("texts");
let pick=dropdown.value;
const title=pick;
let chosenText;


//edit

let text



let letterCount;
let lowercaseText;

document.getElementById("book-title").innerHTML = title;

function changeTextValue() {
  
    pick = dropdown.value;
    if (pick === "huckFinnText") {
         chosenText = huckFinnText;
        console.log(chosenText);
    } else if (pick === "mobyDickText") {
        chosenText = mobyDickText;
        console.log(chosenText);
    } 


//edit

    text=chosenText;
    update();
    //return chosenText;




}








//edit

//console.log(text);
changeTextValue();





document.getElementById("texts").addEventListener("change", changeTextValue);

function countFunction(letter) {
    let letterCount=0;
    lowercaseText=text.toLowerCase();
    for (let i=0; i<=text.length-1; i++) {
      if (letter === lowercaseText.charAt(i)) {
          letterCount++;
      }
    } return letterCount;
  } 





//edit

function update(){
  
  
const a = countFunction("a");
const b = countFunction("b");
const c = countFunction("c");
const d = countFunction("d");
const e = countFunction("e");
const f = countFunction("f");
const g = countFunction("g");
const h = countFunction("h");
const i = countFunction("i");
const j = countFunction("j");
const k = countFunction("k");
const l = countFunction("l");
const m = countFunction("m");
const n = countFunction("n");
const o = countFunction("o");
const p = countFunction("p");
const q = countFunction("q");
const r = countFunction("r");
const s = countFunction("s");
const t = countFunction("t");
const u = countFunction("u");
const v = countFunction("v");
const w = countFunction("w");
const x = countFunction("x");
const y = countFunction("y");
const z = countFunction("z");

const letters = {
    "A": a,
    "B": b,
    "C": c,
    "D": d,
    "E": e,
    "F": f,
    "G": g,
    "H": h,
    "I": i,
    "J": j,
    "K": k,
    "L": l,
    "M": m,
    "N": n,
    "O": o,
    "P": p,
    "Q": q,
    "R": r,
    "S": s,
    "T": t,
    "U": u,
    "V": v,
    "W": w,
    "X": x,
    "Y": y,
    "Z": z
};

let sortable = [];
for (var num in letters) {      //console.log(num,letters[num]);
    sortable.push([num, letters[num]]);
}
const sorted=sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

let sortedNumbers = [];
for (var value in sorted) {
    sortedNumbers.push(sorted[value][1]);
}

let sortedLetters = [];
for (var value in sorted) {
    sortedLetters.push(sorted[value][0]);
}

for (let item=0; item<sorted.length; item++) {
    let strLetter = item.toString();
    document.getElementById(strLetter).innerHTML = sortedLetters[item];
}

for (let item=0; item<sorted.length; item++) {
    let strNumber = item.toString() + "n";
    document.getElementById(strNumber).innerHTML = sortedNumbers[item].toLocaleString();
} 

let total=0;
for (let item=0; item<sorted.length; item++) {
    total += sortedNumbers[item];
} document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toLocaleString();

let percent = [];
for (var num in sortedNumbers) {
    percent.push((sortedNumbers[num] / total) * 100);
    document.getElementById(num + "p").innerHTML = percent[num].toFixed(1) + "%";
}



//edit

}//update
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="main">
        <form id="form">
            <select id= "texts" name="texts" class="select">
                <option value="mobyDickText" id="mobyDick">Moby Dick</option> 
                <option value="huckFinnText" id="huckFinn">Huck Finn</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <table class="result">
            <tbody>
                <th class="title" colspan="3" id="book-title"></th>
                <tr>
                      <td id="0" class="letter"></td>
                      <td id="0n" class="number"></td>
                      <td id="0p" class="percent"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td id="1" class="letter"></td><td id="1n" class="number"></td><td id="1p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="2" class="letter"></td><td id="2n" class="number"></td><td id="2p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="3" class="letter"></td><td id="3n" class="number"></td><td id="3p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="4" class="letter"></td><td id="4n" class="number"></td><td id="4p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="5" class="letter"></td><td id="5n" class="number"></td><td id="5p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="6" class="letter"></td><td id="6n" class="number"></td><td id="6p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="7" class="letter"></td><td id="7n" class="number"></td><td id="7p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="8" class="letter"></td><td id="8n" class="number"></td><td id="8p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="9" class="letter"></td><td id="9n" class="number"></td><td id="9p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="10" class="letter"></td><td id="10n" class="number"></td><td id="10p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="11" class="letter"></td><td id="11n" class="number"></td><td id="11p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="12" class="letter"></td><td id="12n" class="number"></td><td id="12p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="13" class="letter"></td><td id="13n" class="number"></td><td id="13p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="14" class="letter"></td><td id="14n" class="number"></td><td id="14p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="15" class="letter"></td><td id="15n" class="number"></td><td id="15p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="16" class="letter"></td><td id="16n" class="number"></td><td id="16p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="17" class="letter"></td><td id="17n" class="number"></td><td id="17p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="18" class="letter"></td><td id="18n" class="number"></td><td id="18p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="19" class="letter"></td><td id="19n" class="number"></td><td id="19p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="20" class="letter"></td><td id="20n" class="number"></td><td id="20p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="21" class="letter"></td><td id="21n" class="number"></td><td id="21p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="22" class="letter"></td><td id="22n" class="number"></td><td id="22p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="23" class="letter"></td><td id="23n" class="number"></td><td id="23p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="24" class="letter"></td><td id="24n" class="number"></td><td id="24p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td id="25" class="letter"></td><td id="25n" class="number"></td><td id="25p" class="percent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td class="footer" colspan="3" id="total"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- i put the code that updated the table into a function called `update`
- its seems the overall processing was done on a global variable named
  `text`, i didnt call `changeTextValue` to initialise it straight away
- in `changeValueText` rather than returning the value, i assigned it
  to the global variable `text`, then called that `update` function
- i waited until you confirmed the global variable had been set with a
  console.log then manually called your `changeValueText` so that
  `update` function was called and your table showed some results

*yeah you might be a novice but we all started there, your program showed ingenunity and you stroved to push yourself, well done :)*

Comment: Omg thank you. That makes total sense, to place the HTML updates inside a function and call that function within the changeTextValue function. This ensures that the HTML gets updated everytime the mouse event occurs. Genius. Thank you!